# reading compressed files from a URL using read_delim

Tags: r

Is there any other way to read .gz file from a URL using read_delim function from the readr package than using connection? e.g.:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/encodeDCC/wgEncodeHaibMethylRrbs/wgEncodeHaibMethylRrbsImr90UwSitesRep1.bed.gz",destfile=temp,method="curl")
d <- read_delim(gzfile(temp), delim='\t', skip=1)
```

Comment: The documentation says it can be a file, connection or "raw data" (in a string).

Comment: I think my problem is that I'd like to use read_delim just on this compressed file from URL, but I get an error: "Error in collectorsGuess(source, tokenizer, n = 100) : 
  embedded nul in string: '\x89\0". The documentation says that read_delim works with files ‘.gz’, ‘.bz2’, ‘.xz’, or ‘.zip’ and ‘https://’, ‘ftp://’, or ‘ftps://’...

Comment: After downloading the file using `download.file("http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/encodeDCC/wgEncodeHaibMethylRrbs/wgEncodeHaibMethylRrbsImr90UwSitesRep1.bed.gz",
              destfile= "wgEncodeHaibMethylRrbsImr90UwSitesRep1.bed.gz")`, `d <- read_delim(gzfile("wgEncodeHaibMethylRrbsImr90UwSitesRep1.bed.gz"), delim='\t', skip=1)` worked for me.

Comment: but still it isn't reading compressed files directly from a URL. I wrote the issue about it on reader github site.

Comment: I always imagined that if a file is compressed, you need to somehow extract it in order to read it, either server or local side. Oh well...